Present participle or past participle?
I have some difficulty in distinguishing between past and present participles.
I understand that usually we use the -ing form to describe things or persons that are the source of effect and we use the past participle for the receiver of the effect.
However, I think in some cases it is not that simple.
For example, we say:

the company specialising in... [not specialized],

but we also say

the company focused on... [not focusing].

At the same time, speaking about the magazine, we would say

the magazine specialising in...

and

"the magazine focusing on... [not focused]".

Why is it so?
When it comes to a company, one member of this forum (FumbleFingers) suggested that "there doesn't seem to be any "grammatical" rationale for the preference". But is it the same case when we speak about a magazine?
Could anyone please explain to me the difference between the participles in these sentences?
Moreover, I'm confused which participle should I choose in this sentence:

We came out of the cinema (quivered or quivering) with fright.

I looked in the dictionary and "quivering" seems to be the right answer. But is there any rule to determine which one would fit here?
I searched on this and other forums and I also read my grammar books (Murphy, English Grammar in Use; Swan, Practical English Usage), but I found no information which would provide answers to my questions.
I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

The answer that you link to shows that we do say 'a company focusing on', just less often than 'focused'.
We is the subject of the verb quiver. The cinema patrons are quivering, not 'being quivered'. Similarly with specialise.
Focus is a bit different because it's a metaphor relating to rays of light. You can imagine the company 'focusing its attention' on a particular area, or being itself like the rays which are 'focused on' it.

In your example of "the company focused on....", the word 'focused' could be read as a verb. You are speaking about an action (to focus) the company did in the past. And there are two things you could take from such a statement without further information - that the company no longer focuses on [x], or that the company doesn't exist anymore. When you use the past participle rather than the present, it is tacit that it is no longer happening in the present.
If you're speaking about a company that currently exists and functions, you could use "focuses" or "focusing", depending on the context.

"The company focuses on profits" is a simple statement using the present tense of the verb to show what they currently do.
"I would not choose the company that focuses on profits" adds a descriptive clause to identify a company, or the kind of company that you are referring to
"I would choose the company focusing on customer service" uses the word as a participle adjective to describe the company or kind of company referred to.


But this last example is ambiguous. It could also mean, “In choosing the company, I would focus on customer service.”

@PaulTanenbaum it would need a comma to mean that. But either way, it doesn't change answer to the OP's question.

Yes, it would indeed need a comma to correctly punctuatedly mean that. And no, it doesn’t invalidate your answer. But your wording is “If you’re speaking,” and speech is bereft of commas.
